# Quiero mostrar elementos en una web al hacer scroll pero solo me funciona con una de las clases creadas en el html

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Quiero mostrar elementos en la web al hacer scroll pero solo me funciona con una de las clases.
Si intento añadir elementos ya no funciona ninguno. En el siguiente código, funciona perfectamente para la clase "parrafosmov", y todos los párrafos hacen lo que quiero, pero estoy intentando añadir este mismo efecto al Id "sintomasArticle". Lo he intentado añadir al mismo código como otra variable más y no funciona. También en otro documento JS pero de ninguna manera. Al id "sintomasArticle" no se le aplica el código. No solo esto, sino que al añadirlo, los párrafos tampoco funcionan.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {

let element = document.getElementsByClassName('parrafosmov');
let elementSintomas= document.getElementsById('sintomasArticle');
let screenSize = window.innerHeight;

if(elementSintomas.getBoundingClientRect().top +300 < screenSize) {
    elementSintomas.classList.add('visible');
  } else {
    elementSintomas.classList.remove('visible');
  }

for (let index = 0; index < element.length; index++) {
  const elements = element[index];
  if(elements.getBoundingClientRect().top +300 < screenSize) {
    elements.classList.add('visible');
  } else {
    elements.classList.remove('visible');
  }
}
```

});

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    let element = document.getElementsByClassName('parrafosmov');
    let screenSize = window.innerHeight;

    for (let index = 0; index < element.length; index++) {
      const elements = element[index];
      if(elements.getBoundingClientRect().top +300 < screenSize) {
        elements.classList.add('visible');
      } else {
        elements.classList.remove('visible');
      }
    }
  });
```

```css
.parrafosmov {
  padding-top: 50px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 white, 0 2px 0 #c9c9c9, 0 6px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
    0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
    0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25),
    0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(-10vh, 0vh);
  transition: all 1s;
}
.seccion2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
}
  
#sintomasArticle {
  margin-top: 75px;
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(-10vh, 0vh);
  transition: all 1s;
  
}
.sintomas {
  margin-left: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "mifuente";
  font-size: auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.05em #e95f35, 0 0 0.2em #e72e19, 0 0 0.3em #d80505;
}
.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

```html
<section class="seccion2" >
      <article class="parrafosmov">
        <h2>¿Qué síntomas puedo experimentar?</h2><br><br><br>
        <p> Tanto la Hemodiálisis, como la diálisis peritoneal, a la cual 
          dedicaremos un apartado más adelante, son tratamientos  
          de suma importancia, ya que mantienen con vida a la persona hasta la           llegada de 
          un riñón compatible. 
        </p><br><br>
        <p>No obstante, como en cualquier otro tratamiento, pueden aparecer             una serie de 
          efectos secundarios y adversos que pueden ponernos en riesgo durante           la terapia.
        </p><br><br>
        <p>Es por ello que quiero que aprendas los más frecuentes.
          La mayoría de síntomas, si se consiguen identificar a tiempo, 
          son relativamente fácil de eliminar. 
        </p><br><br>
        <p>¡¡ No dudes en avisar a tu enfermera con cualquier cosa diferente!!         </p>
      </article>
      
      </section>
      <article id="sintomasArticle" class="sintomasJs">
        <div class="sintomas">DOLOR DE CABEZA</div>
        <div class="sintomas">MAREO</div>
        <div class="sintomas">NAUSEAS</div>
        <div class="sintomas">CALAMBRES</div>
        <div class="sintomas">HORMIGUEO</div>
        <div class="sintomas">SOFOCO</div>
      </article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código funciona bien, el único problema es que tu `article` de síntomas no tiene suficiente espacio para bajar y que se ponga en la posición que se necesita. Si agregas un montón de br funciona bien, por lo que solo debes ajustar los espacios como mejor te parezca.

Igual cambié el `magicNumber` de `300` por `screenSize/2` para que no importa el tamaño de la pantalla salga más centrado

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    let element = [
      ...document.getElementsByClassName('sintomasJs'),
      ...document.getElementsByClassName('parrafosmov'),
    ]
    let screenSize = window.innerHeight;

    for (let index = 0; index < element.length; index++) {
      const elements = element[index];
      if(elements.getBoundingClientRect().top + (screenSize /2) < screenSize) {
        elements.classList.add('visible');
      } else {
        elements.classList.remove('visible');
      }
    }
  });
```

```css
.parrafosmov {
  padding-top: 50px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 white, 0 2px 0 #c9c9c9, 0 6px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
    0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
    0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25),
    0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(-10vh, 0vh);
  transition: all 1s;
}
.seccion2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
}
  
#sintomasArticle {
  margin-top: 75px;
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(-10vh, 0vh);
  transition: all 1s;
  
}
.sintomas {
  margin-left: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "mifuente";
  font-size: auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.05em #e95f35, 0 0 0.2em #e72e19, 0 0 0.3em #d80505;
}
.visible {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

```html
<section class="seccion2" >
      <article class="parrafosmov">
        <h2>¿Qué síntomas puedo experimentar?</h2><br><br><br>
        <p> Tanto la Hemodiálisis, como la diálisis peritoneal, a la cual 
          dedicaremos un apartado más adelante, son tratamientos  
          de suma importancia, ya que mantienen con vida a la persona hasta la           llegada de 
          un riñón compatible. 
        </p><br><br>
        <p>No obstante, como en cualquier otro tratamiento, pueden aparecer             una serie de 
          efectos secundarios y adversos que pueden ponernos en riesgo durante           la terapia.
        </p><br><br>
        <p>Es por ello que quiero que aprendas los más frecuentes.
          La mayoría de síntomas, si se consiguen identificar a tiempo, 
          son relativamente fácil de eliminar. 
        </p><br><br>
        <p>¡¡ No dudes en avisar a tu enfermera con cualquier cosa diferente!!         </p>
      </article>
      
      </section>
      <article id="sintomasArticle" class="sintomasJs">
        <div class="sintomas">DOLOR DE CABEZA</div>
        <div class="sintomas">MAREO</div>
        <div class="sintomas">NAUSEAS</div>
        <div class="sintomas">CALAMBRES</div>
        <div class="sintomas">HORMIGUEO</div>
        <div class="sintomas">SOFOCO</div>
      </article>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br><br>
      <br><br>
      <br><br>
      <br><br>
      <br><br>
      <br><br>
      <br>
      <br>
      
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
```

Comment: Correcto, además veo el código mas ordenado y he aprendido algo que no sabía. Veo que puedo declarar todas las clases en un array bajo el identificador element y acceder a todas desde ahi. Muchas gracias